# Using Kubernetes with Skaffold and running Next JS produces "Your connection is not private" under HTTPS in Chrome

Tags: javascript, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, skaffold

I'm running Skaffold with a few apps in Development :

**Skaffold.yaml**

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:    
    - image: MYDOCKERID/client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: '**/*.js'
            dest: .
```

**Dockerfile of client :**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

**client-depl.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: MYDOCKERID/client
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

When executing `skaffold dev` from command line everything is compiled perfectly :

```
[92m[client-depl-5bdc8cffcd-s9z9r client] [0mevent - compiled successfully
[92m[client-depl-5bdc8cffcd-s9z9r client] [0mwait  - compiling...
[92m[client-depl-5bdc8cffcd-s9z9r client] [0mAttention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[92m[client-depl-5bdc8cffcd-s9z9r client] [0mThis information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[92m[client-depl-5bdc8cffcd-s9z9r client] [0mYou can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[92m[client-depl-5bdc8cffcd-s9z9r client] [0mhttps://nextjs.org/telemetry
[92m[client-depl-5bdc8cffcd-s9z9r client] [0m
[92m[client-depl-5bdc8cffcd-s9z9r client] [0mevent - compiled successfully
```

I've added the domain in Hosts file in Windows etc folder :

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 ticketing.dev
```

However when typing in Chrome `ticketing.dev` I get :

[image]

How can I run the app in Chrome and overcome this message ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a certificate to have your connection secure. You will also need to configure the `ingress` to use the cert that you create.

You should read [Manage TLS Certificates in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/).

> Kubernetes provides a `certificates.k8s.io` API, which lets you provision TLS certificates signed by a Certificate Authority (CA) that you control. These CA and certificates can be used by your workloads to establish trust.

You can have a look into a nice guide on how to [Adding SSL/TLS support to applications in Kubernetes-native way](https://medium.com/@cloudark/adding-ssl-tls-support-to-applications-in-kubernetes-native-way-dd31f016ac5e).

You can create a self-signed certificate, [this medium article](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/generating-self-signed-certificates-on-windows-7812a600c2d8) shows how to do that on Windows.

On Linux you can do following:

```
[root]# mkdir certs
[root]# openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout certs/ticketing.key -out certs/ticketing.csr -subj "/C=/ST=/L=/O=/OU=/CN=default"
[root]# openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in certs/ticketing.csr -signkey certs/ticketing.key -out certs/ticketing.crt
```

This will create a cert that is valid for 365 days.
Then create a `secret` which will hold your cert:

```
kubectl create secret generic ticketing-certs --from-file=certs -n default
```

Once the cert and `secret` is ready you should create an `ingress`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: example1-ingress
spec:
tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.ticketing.dev
    secretName: ticketing-cert
  rules:
  - host: www.ticketing.dev
  http:
   paths:
   - path: /
   backend:
     serviceName: client-srv
     servicePort: 3000
```

Let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: missing indentation from tls to secretName

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the project for development purposes. If you want to run the app on chrome. To bypass this security warning, just right this on the webpage showing warning blindly :

`thisisunsafe`